# IBM Cloud command-line interface

Tags: command-line-interface

i have to  install IBM Cloud command-line interface locally on my Laptop.

i have installed it but i cannot run the command on my command prompt

ibmcloud target -o  aashish.raina@ymail.com  -s dev

says ORG name not found.

but the fact is that i can see the ORG name in my IBM cloud.

i have installed it but i cannot run the command on my command prompt

ibmcloud target -o  aashish.raina@ymail.com  -s dev

ibmcloud target -o  aashish.raina@ymail.com  -s dev

says ORG name not found.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
ibmcloud cf orgs
```

to get the list of all org that is bound to your username under your api like - https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net .If you don't find the required org add the org / space from the account manager role. 
For further information
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud?topic=cloud-cli-ibmcloud_commands_account#ibmcloud_account_org_user_add

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to see in which region the ORG that you see in the CF is created.
It could be in any one of the regions, us-east, us-south, ap-south, ap-north, uk-south, or eu-gb.

So, run thru each region to see where your ORG is created ( as I understand you have already created or you see it in the CF portal )

This lists the ORGs in the default region that your instance was created.
I'd assume that your ORG was not found in the default region.
So do this below.

```
$ibmcloud account orgs
```

If your ORG was not created here, this above command will list that there are NO Orgs.

Run thru each region as shown, until you see your ORG in the result.

```
$ibmcloud account orgs -r us-east
$ibmcloud account orgs -r us-south
$ibmcloud....
$ibmcloud account orgs -r eu-gb
```

Assuming that you found your ORG in eu-gb, run this command below.

```
$ibmcloud target -o YourOrgFoundInCF -r eu-gb -s DefaultSpaceFoundInCF
```

This should succeed.